# JAVASCRIPT - Sound Effect

Tags: javascript

i wanted to know that how to produce a sound effect after read code successfully in Javascript. For example when we are scan the qr code, then it would come out sound such as "beep".

Answer (score 0):

Create a function:

```
    function beep() {
    let sound = new Audio("audio.mp3");  
    sound.play();
 }
    beep();
```